# How to write or index data in SOLR using pentaho kettle?

Tags: solr, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to read data from MySQL and Oracle tables and load or index data in SOLR. How I can achieve this using Penatho kettle.

Please help. Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran across this, probably the OP has solved their issue already or given up, but for the benefit of others I'll share my (somewhat dated) experience with pentaho for this. Five or six years ago I had a client for which pentaho was the required ETL, and IIRC there was a Solr plugin, but it wasn't very good and we wound up writing our own solr plugin (including building the required UI components, etc.). Even with the custom plugin Pentaho was very database centric and didn't understand multi-value fields very well, having to encode/decode as comma separated lists (with all the usual fun regarding quoting/escaping). It also allowed users to do dangerous things like attempt to sort a data stream, which just doesn't work well for non-batch use cases, or for large data sets. As such, if at all possible I'd recommend not using Pentaho for this task. Some things you might consider instead include:

**Small/Simple Data**

If you're just exploring Solr's capabilities, won't be joining tables or transforming the data in the rows and are dealing with thousands of rows not millions, you may find the [Data Import Handler](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_8/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler) to be a sufficient tool. Likely someone will comment that they used it for many millions or that they handled complex case X.. but it tends to become unwieldy and hard to manage if you push it out of it's comfort zone. One of the most common consulting scenarios I get is someone who started with DIH and has grown beyond it either in terms of scale or in terms of data complexity.

**Medium Data**

If you are dealing with a few million documents, want to transform (i.e. the data is in XML, dates need formatting, fields renamed, etc) or enrich the documents with custom code easily plugged in, or want to pre-analyze fields to take load off of Solr you may wish to check out a tool I built called [JesterJ](https://github.com/nsoft/jesterj)

At one point it looked like [Hydra](http://findwise.github.io/Hydra/) was going to become the go-to solution at this level but it has seen no commits in the last 7 years now.

**Big Data**

There's no single answer if you're handling hundreds of millions or billions of documents. At this scale you likely have other requirements as well, if auditing and provinence are important, [Apache Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/), may be a good tool to look at, if you have data that arrives in large batches and needs to be processed at maximum speed, or sufficient data flow to occupy multiple machines continuously transformations as [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) jobs that can be scaled across [AWS EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) instances might suit your needs. Everything at this level requires significant coding/configuration and time investment, and as such there are many other possible options.